# Why isn't manager attribute changing on distinguished name modification in Sun Directory Server 6.3?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sun, directory-server

I have a problem with manager attribute in Sun Directory Server.
I set this attribute for a user in the directory, e.g. cn=testmanager,dc=test,dc=com and when I change manager's dn this change is not propagated in manager attributes.

For example:

I have two users:

```
dn: cn=testmanager,dc=test,dc=com
```

and

```
dn: cn=testperson,dc=test,com
manager: cn=testmanager,dc=test,dc=com
```

Then I modify manager's dn to:

```
dn: cn=testmanagerchange,dc=test,dc=com
```

But manager attribute in cn=testperson,dc=test,com doesn't change is still equal to cn=testmanager,dc=test,dc=com. In Active Directory it works fine.

Exact definition of attribute:

```
Name:  manager  
OID:  0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.10  
Aliases:  -  
Origin:  RFC 1274  
Description:  Standard LDAP attribute type  
Syntax:  1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12 (DN)  
Multivalued:  Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

In Sun Directory Server you have to set the list of attributes that should keep reference integrity. Some attributes are set by default, however you have to manually add manager attribute.

This is an article that explains this issue: http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-2763/fsush?a=view.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This may not directly help, but it may depend on how Sun Directory Server handles DN syntax attributes.  I can speak with experience for eDirectory, where DN syntax attributes do what you want automagically.

I.e. You can rename, move, or delete an object, and all DN syntax references to it will automatically update themselves.  (Actually for renames and moves they do not actually update, rather when they convert the internal database ID value for the object to display the pretty human readable name, it always shows the current value.  Clean up after deletes are handled differently).

The question becomes, how does Sun Directory Server handle these cases.

Though it is interesting that manager can be multivalued.  That would suck, having several managers!